# TeamCity commit sub folder should not trigger build

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a project in TeamCity that triggers a CI build on a Subversion commit and its working great,  however I now need the project to ignore a build request if a users makes any changes to some projects within the solutions.

I have looked through this documentation http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-Triggerabuildonchangesinsnapshotdependencies and applied everything I can think of to stop the trigger.  This what I currently have set

-:root=MyPlanetfootprintCom_PlanetFootprint;comment=.:PF.EDGE.LEGACY/PF.EDGE/PF.EDGE.PROCESSORS/PF.EDGE.PROCESSORS/**

As I understand it, I would of though if any user committed any code for any project or file under the PF.EDGE.LEGACY/PF.EDGE/PF.EDGE.PROCESSORS/PF.EDGE.PROCESSORS/** directory it will not trigger this TeamCity build?  is this correct.

I am really struggling with this one, I have looked through all the other answers to similar questions and they all seem to do the same thing I am doing but I am sure there is something very stupid that I am doing wrong

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed it, it looks like you need to set a over-riding do not include first, which -:. does and then I can set the projects/folders I do want a build to be triggered from.

```
-:.
+:MY.PLANETFOOTPRINT.COM\**
+:SERVICES\**
+:PF.QUEUE\**
+:REFERENCES\**
+:PlanetFootprint2015.sln
+:nuget\**
+:packages\**
```

This will cause the build to stay at pending, but is overwritten one of the "allowed" folders are checked in.